# How to neutralize border-left: 0 none with overriding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two css in my page first: bootstrap css and second my customized style.
In Bootstrap has an style definition: `border-left: 0 none;` and in second style I want to neutralize it.
How can I do it?

Comment: can you please share your code or make a JSFiddle of it?

Comment: Add new style relative to the parent..ex..#wrapper .left-border{ border-left: #ccc 1px solid }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `border-left: initial;`

"The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value." - [W3 Schools | Initial Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: black;
}
div {
  border-left: 10px;
}
div {
  border-left: initial;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/nhkuu7ks/

Answer (score 0):

would have been better had you shared your code. but, just to provide a solution, what you can do is style your HTML tags using BootStrap via. class name as a reference and you can use ID of the HTML tag as a reference to override the CSS given using a class as the reference.

you can also use inline CSS which would override any other CSS provided to the HTML tag but it's not considered a good practice in general.